# Docker $(pwd) and bash aliases

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I'm running Docker CE in Ubuntu 16.04. I've created a Docker image for the polymer-cli. 
The idea is to be able to run polymer commands from inside disposable docker containers using bash aliases that mount the current directory, run the command and then destroy the container, like this:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/home/node/app -u node fresnizky/polymer-cli polymer
```

This works perfectlty, but if I create a bash alias for this command:

```
alias polymer="docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/home/node/app -u node fresnizky/polymer-cli polymer "
```

Then $(pwd) points to my home directory instead of my current directory.

Anyone knows how I can solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that, as you have used double quotes, the command substitution is being done at the time of `alias` declaration, not afterwards.

Use single quotes:

```
alias polymer='docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/home/node/app -u node fresnizky/polymer-cli polymer'
```

Also, instead of using the `pwd` command substitution, `$(pwd)` you can use the environment variable `PWD` expansion, `$PWD`, which will expand to the same value. In fact, `pwd` command also gets its value from the `PWD` variable.

Comment: For Windows, I had to use `${pwd}` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share, for those who have issue with `$PWD` on Windows, cuz it will show just empty, my TL came with great solution for all platforms:

> docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD:-.}:/home/node/app -u node fresnizky/polymer-cli polymer