# If I run this command through make file it says "No such file or directory"

Tags: docker, powershell, shell, makefile

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
    
    ENV_TYPE:=dev
    USER:=$(shell id -u)
    
    
    generate-client-win:
    docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i /local/openapi.spec.yaml -c /local/openapi.config.yaml -g dart-dio -o /local/dart-dio-client
```

My make file looks like above and I am trying to run in from PowerShell in windows.

If I run the command manually in the powershell it runs fine, but I am trying to run it through make file and I enter:

```
make generate-client-win
```

Then I get the following error:

```
[main] ERROR o.o.c.config.CodegenConfigurator - /local/openapi.config.yaml (No such file or directory)
[main] ERROR o.o.c.config.CodegenConfigurator - /local/openapi.config.yaml (No such file or directory)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deserialize config file: /local/openapi.config.yaml
```

I assure that the files are there in the directory from where I am running this make file.

Comment: Why do you have a colon after ${PWD} ?

Comment: I do not know :/

Comment: see following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259515/docker-pwd-and-bash-aliases?force_isolation=true   Do you have a folder local where you start executing the powershell script?